# Merging data in Pandas dataframe by values in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
Name    Year    Sales
Ann     2010    500
Ann     2011    500
Bob     2010    400
Bob     2011    700
Ed      2010    300
Ed      2011    300
```

I want to be able to combine the figures in the sales column for each name returning:

```
Name    Sales
Ann     1000
Bob     1100
Ed      600
```

Perhaps I need a for loop to go through and combine the 2 values for both years and create a new column, but I'm not quite sure. Is there a pandas function that can help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a simple dataframe [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

In that case you'll just have to select the two columns you need

```
df = df[["Name", "Sales"]]
```

And then apply the `groupby`

```py
df.groupby(["name"], as_index=False).sum()
```

By default the `groupby` will make the grouped by columns part of the index. If you want to keep them as colum you need to specify `as_index=False`